# select statement inside after trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get last inserted value using trigger, I am trying following query, please suggest me how can I get this or please tell me if this is possible with another way.

```
CREATE TRIGGER user 
AFTER INSERT ON wp_user
FOR EACH ROW 
Select NEW.user_name from wp_user;
```

Comment: Why not just add a timestamp column to your `wp_user` table, and query according to it?

Comment: how can I do this using timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment above: assuming the `wp_user` table has a `last_modified` timestamp column, you could update it with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_modification
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON wp_user
FOR EACH ROW 
NEW.last_modified = NOW();
```

Having done that, you could just query the user with the latest date:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     wp_user
ORDER BY last_modified DESC
LIMIT    1
```